# Piacasa Api error Invalid Token

Tags: php, gdata-api, picasa

Hi i am using Google Gdata Api in php. I am getting an error

> **"Error: Expected response code 200,
>   got 403 Token invalid - AuthSub token
>   has wrong scope"**.

What should i do. What's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using a wrong base url for your queries.
The correct base url for the Picasa Web Albums is `http://picasaweb.google.com/data/`

Comment: so what's the url you're querying?